# Laravel Polymorphic relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Im having a bit of trouble to figure out how to make the polymorphic relations work, to create my dynamic user content as shown below.

my plan is to display **content** depending on the **content_type** and the link between is the **id** from the Users table and the **user_id** form UserData table. Those are both models too **Users** and **UserData**

**Users table**

```
*id*    *username*  *password* 
1       johndoe     123
2       janedoe     321
```

**UserData table**

```
*user_id    *content*         *content_type*
1           John Doe          full_name
1           john-doe.jpg      avatar
1           laravel           twitter
1           blue              favorite_color
2           Jane Doe          full_name
2           jane-doe.jpg      avatar
2           Eloquent          twitter
2           green             favorite_color
```

I hope someone can see what my purpose here is and know a solution. AND maybe show how

Comment: I'm not sure what you want as a result. Do you want to say: "give me content_type 'avatar' from user with id 1"?

Comment: what you need is one-to-many relation, not polymorphic